# How to get variants of OHLC resampling

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a data_frame d1:

```
Date        Open     High      Low    Close
2019-07-15  1.25736  1.25782  1.25105  1.25162
2019-07-16  1.25161  1.25207  1.23963  1.24056
2019-07-17  1.24056  1.24564  1.23825  1.24362
2019-07-18  1.24330  1.25585  1.24282  1.25470
2019-07-19  1.25470  1.25562  1.24778  1.25015
2019-07-20  1.25070  1.25139  1.24559  1.24776
2019-07-21  1.24766  1.24816  1.24180  1.24391
2019-07-22  1.24394  1.25220  1.24278  1.24837
2019-07-23  1.24837  1.25175  1.24369  1.24543
2019-07-24  1.24540  1.24597  1.23765  1.23867
2019-07-25  1.23806  1.23840  1.22123  1.22175
2019-07-26  1.22184  1.22260  1.21200  1.21517
2019-07-27  1.21517  1.22488  1.21350  1.21532
2019-07-28  1.21533  1.21704  1.20798  1.21191
2019-07-29  1.21191  1.21696  1.20902  1.21496
2019-07-30  1.21511  1.21883  1.21018  1.21443
2019-07-31  1.21445  1.22091  1.21358  1.21696
```

I would like to create variants of higher period, let say 2D.
I am using the resample() method to done with this.

```
d2_1 = d1.resample('2d').apply(
    {
        'Open': 'first',
        'High': 'max',
        'Low': 'min',
        'Close': 'last'
    })
```

And get the result:

```
Date        Open     High      Low    Close
2019-07-15  1.25736  1.25782  1.23963  1.24056
2019-07-17  1.24056  1.25585  1.23825  1.25470
2019-07-19  1.25470  1.25562  1.24559  1.24776
2019-07-21  1.24766  1.25220  1.24180  1.24837
2019-07-23  1.24837  1.25175  1.23765  1.23867
2019-07-25  1.23806  1.23840  1.21200  1.21517
2019-07-27  1.21517  1.22488  1.20798  1.21191
2019-07-29  1.21191  1.21883  1.20902  1.21443
2019-07-31  1.21445  1.22091  1.21217  1.21431
```

But this is only one variant of 2D1 period, where start point is the first row of D1.

I don't know, how to create a 2D2 period, where start point will be a second row:

```
2019-07-16  1.25161  1.25207  1.23963  1.24056
```

So, I am expecting to get the result:

```
2019-07-16  1.25161  1.25207  1.23963  1.24056
2019-07-18  1.24330  1.25585  1.24282  1.25470
2019-07-20  1.25070  1.25139  1.24559  1.24776
2019-07-22  1.24394  1.25220  1.24278  1.24837
2019-07-24  1.24540  1.24597  1.23765  1.23867
2019-07-26  1.22184  1.22260  1.21200  1.21517
2019-07-28  1.21533  1.21704  1.20798  1.21191
2019-07-30  1.21511  1.21883  1.21018  1.21443
```

How could I accomplish this?
Is there a parameter to set start point of resampling?

Answer (score 0):

How about slicing the data before resampling?

```
df2.iloc[1:].resample('2d').apply({'Open': 'first','High': 'max','Low':'min','Close': 'last'})
```